# unable to write data to RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am running pyspark on windows and implementing an algorithm that was previously implemented in python

I have converted the list to RDD but got the error

```
voxel =[[ ['0' for col in range(100)] for col in range(100)] for row in range(6)] 
delay = sc.parallelize(voxel,4)
locationforant=[[75,15],[100,50],[75,80],[25,80],[0,50],[25,15]]
for a in range(6):
    for x in range(100):
        for y in range(100):
            distance=((math.sqrt((x-locationforant[a][0])**2+(y-locationforant[a][1])**2))/100)*200
            delay[a][x][y] = round(distance)
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-b81a67e36764> in <module>()
     21             distance=((math.sqrt((x-locationforant[a][0])**2+(y-locationforant[a][1])**2))/100)*200
     22 #             breakpoint()
---> 23             delay[a][x][y] = round(distance)

TypeError: 'RDD' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: Spark is meant to be distributed, therefore even the triple nested for loop isn't correct for Spark as it would be executed on every machine where the Spark executors run. Also, RDD just is not accessible like Python lists at all.. Start by converting your code to Pandas dataframes, which would be closer to getting a Spark-like algorithm

Comment: Thanks, I used map function and it solve the problem somehow, but what's the alternative solution for nested loops in pyspark. Sorry but I am new to spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error indicates, you cannot use the index operator (`[]`) on an RDD.  You'll need to use something like [`map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.map) to apply a function to each row.